# JTextPane Coloured Words Not working

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

So I created a simple JFrame and added a JTextPane to it to create a sorta console..

I have the following methods and variables in my class which is supposed to change the colour of text in the JTextPane.

```
private static final Object CurrentConsoleAttributes[] = new Object[4];
private static final SimpleAttributeSet ConsoleAttributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();

public Object[] getConsoleAttributes() {
    CurrentConsoleAttributes[0] = StyleConstants.getForeground(ConsoleAttributes);
    CurrentConsoleAttributes[1] = StyleConstants.getBackground(ConsoleAttributes);
    CurrentConsoleAttributes[2] = StyleConstants.isBold(ConsoleAttributes);
    CurrentConsoleAttributes[3] = StyleConstants.isItalic(ConsoleAttributes);
    return CurrentConsoleAttributes;
}

public void setConsoleAttributes(Color Foreground, Color Background, boolean Bold, boolean Italics) {
    synchronized(ConsoleAttributes) {
        StyleConstants.setForeground(ConsoleAttributes, Foreground);
        StyleConstants.setBackground(ConsoleAttributes, Background);
        StyleConstants.setBold(ConsoleAttributes, Bold);
        StyleConstants.setItalic(ConsoleAttributes, Italics);
    }
}

private void setOutputAreaText(final String Text) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  //I read that I need to use this when dealing with swing and JTextPane is a swing component.
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                StyledDocument Document = Frame.this.OutputArea.getStyledDocument();
                Document.insertString(Document.getLength(), Text, ConsoleAttributes);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void WriteLine(Object Value) {        
    try {
        System.out.print("Hey");
        setConsoleAttributes(java.awt.Color.red, Color.white, true, false);
        System.out.print("Testing");

        setConsoleAttributes(java.awt.Color.blue, Color.white, true, false);
        System.out.println("Printing");
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        Ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, when I call WriteLine, the entire line is written in blue or whatever colour was used last. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: and with hardcoded value as local variable for Document

Comment: I figured out what was wrong.. Using SwingUtilities part made it not work as it printed everything in the last colour used. I remove the swing utilities and just print and it works just fine! I have no clue why but it works without it.

Comment: Using `invokeLater()` like this is required to update `document` from another thread; it's not required if you're already running on the event dispatch thread (EDT).

Comment: Use proper variable names. Variable names DO NOT start with an upper case character.